# How to dynamically add a variable to a JSON structure in Apex?

Tags: apex, json

I need to add this variable to a Json structure and I'm not being able to do so:

```
public static void getZabixxHostGroups(String result){
    
    String json = '{'+
        '    \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",'+
        '    \"method\": \"host.get\",'+
        '    \"params\": {'+
        '        \"output\": [\"host\"],'+
        '        \"groupids\": [1235]'+
        '    },'+
        '    \"auth\": ' + '\'' + result + '\'' +
        '    \"id\": 1'+
        '}';
    
    String endpoint = 'https://zabbix.eurona.info/api_jsonrpc.php';
    SendingZabbixServices.zabbixDoPost(json, endpoint);
    
}
```

This is the method and I need to concatenate the 'result' parameter passed to the function to the String json variable so I can then continue calling the next function.

Check this line:

```
 '    \"auth\": ' + '\'' + result + '\'' +
```

I've been trying many different ways but none is working fine, always getting some sort of error.

The json structure needs to be like this:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "output": ["host"],
        "groupids": [1235]
    },
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "id": 1
}
```

but in this line `"auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` I need to replace `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` for the value in the 'result' variable so I can make it dinamic.

Any help would be more than appreaciated.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not write your own JSON. This is always problematic. Instead, serialize an object:

```
String payload = JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> { 
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
        'method' => 'host.get',
        'params' => 
            new Map<String, Object> {
                'output' => new String[] { 'host' },
                'groupids' => new Integer[] { 1235 }
            },
        'auth' => result,
        'id' => 1
    }
);
```

This makes it really easy to get your JSON right without any complications.

Comment: Great minds think alike eh... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Might be easier to create a map and serialize it.

```
Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new Map<String,Object>{
  'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
  'params' => new Map<String,Object>{ 
     'output' => new String[]{'host'},
     'groupids' => new Integer[]{1235}
   },
   'auth' => yourAuthString
  },
```

Then just serialize it for the string:

```
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(jsonMap);
```